# How do I install the experimental 3d Nvidia drivers?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 3d, jockey

they used to show up as available for download in Jockey/additional-drivers but now the option is no longer there.

Answer (score 1):

For installing and running the latest experimental and thus possibly **unstable** video drivers you could add the [xorg-edgers ppa](https://launchpad.net/~xorg-edgers/+archive/ppa) to your sources and install from there.

**[Please find the time to read the release notes including notes on how to remove this ppa in case your video output becomes unstable](https://launchpad.net/~xorg-edgers/+archive/ppa)**

Comment: I had one as option when installing 11.04 :).